# Hautelook Alice Faker With MongoDB (ODM) cannot declare in services.yml

Tags: symfony, phpunit, symfony-3.4

I have Symfony Application which using MongoDB and I am trying to install Hautelook Alice Faker into my application. So I did follow exactly the same as [this documentation](https://github.com/hautelook/AliceBundle) and [this documentation](https://github.com/theofidry/AliceDataFixtures#doctrine-odm). When I try to register inside my `services.yml` file and run `./bin/console` It showed the following error.

> The service "hautelook_alice.data_fixtures.loader.file_resolver_loader" has a dependency on a non-existent service "fidry_alice_data_fixtures.doctrine.purger_loader".

Below is how i installed in `serivice.yml` file.

```
    fidry_alice_data_fixtures.persistence.purger_factory.doctrine:
      class: Fidry\AliceDataFixtures\Bridge\Doctrine\Purger\Purger
      arguments:
        - '@doctrine_mongodb.odm.document_manager'
```

Also, I am already registered in `AppKernal.php` as follow

```
 if (in_array($this->getEnvironment(), ['dev', 'test'], true)) {
            $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\DebugBundle\DebugBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\SensioDistributionBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Nelmio\Alice\Bridge\Symfony\NelmioAliceBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Fidry\AliceDataFixtures\Bridge\Symfony\FidryAliceDataFixturesBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Hautelook\AliceBundle\HautelookAliceBundle();

            if ('dev' === $this->getEnvironment()) {
                $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\SensioGeneratorBundle();
                $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\WebServerBundle\WebServerBundle();
            }
        }
```

This is my composer.json file

```
{
    "name": "mma/mmb",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "type": "project",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "AppBundle\\": "src/AppBundle"
        },
        "classmap": [
            "app/AppKernel.php",
            "app/AppCache.php"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        },
        "files": [
            "vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/VarDumper/Resources/functions/dump.php"
        ]
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=7.1",
        "ext-intl": "*",
        "ext-json": "*",
        "ext-mongodb": "^1.5.3",
        "aws/aws-sdk-php": "^3.0",
        "bankofmaldives/bml-connect-php": "^2.0",
        "beepsolutions/beep-php": "^2.0",
        "defuse/php-encryption": "^2.2",
        "doctrine/dbal": "^2.6.0",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^1.6",
        "doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle": "^3.5.0",
        "doctrine/orm": "^2.6",
        "donatj/phpuseragentparser": "^0.15.0",
        "dziki/monolog-sentry-bundle": "^1.0",
        "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "~2.0",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "^2.0",
        "intercom/intercom-php": "3.1",
        "intriro/csv-bundle": "^1.0",
        "jms/serializer": "^3.6",
        "knplabs/knp-gaufrette-bundle": "^0.5.0",
        "knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle": "2.8.0",
        "mailjet/mailjet-apiv3-php": "1.3.0",
        "mailjet/mailjet-bundle": "^1.0",
        "misteio/cloudinary-bundle": "^0.2.0",
        "oneup/uploader-bundle": "^2.2",
        "onfido/api-php-client": "^3.1.0",
        "ornicar/gravatar-bundle": "^1.1",
        "pmill/aws-cognito": "dev-master",
        "pomelopay/pomelopay-connect-php": "^2.0",
        "samiaraboglu/one-signal-api-bundle": "^2.0",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "^5.0.19",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^5.0.0",
        "stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle": "1.3",
        "surfnet/messagebird-api-client-bundle": "^4.1",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.1.0",
        "symfony/polyfill-apcu": "^1.0",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^2.6.4",
        "symfony/symfony": "3.4.*",
        "twig/extensions": "^1.5",
        "twig/twig": "^1.0||^2.0",
        "vich/uploader-bundle": "1.11.0",
        "willdurand/negotiation": "^2.3"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "alcaeus/mongo-php-adapter": "^1.1",
        "doctrine/data-fixtures": "^1.4",
        "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "^3.3",
        "doctrine/mongodb-odm": "^1.1",
        "hautelook/alice-bundle": "^2.7",
        "phpstan/phpstan": "^0.12.33",
        "roave/security-advisories": "dev-master",
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "^3.0",
        "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "^3.5",
        "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "5.1.3",
        "theofidry/alice-data-fixtures": "^1.2"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "symfony-scripts": [
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "@symfony-scripts"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@symfony-scripts"
        ],
        "test": "./vendor/bin/simple-phpunit -c ./phpunit.xml ./tests",
        "phpcs": "./vendor/bin/phpcs --extensions=php --standard=PSR2 ./src/*",
        "stan" : "./vendor/bin/phpstan analyse --level=7 ./src"
    },
    "config": {
        "sort-packages": true,
        "platform": {
            "ext-mongo": "1.6.16"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "extra": {
        "symfony-app-dir": "app",
        "symfony-bin-dir": "bin",
        "symfony-var-dir": "var",
        "symfony-web-dir": "web",
        "symfony-tests-dir": "tests",
        "symfony-assets-install": "relative",
        "incenteev-parameters": {
            "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
        },
        "branch-alias": null
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "https://github.com/onfido/api-php-client.git"
        }
    ]
}
```

Did I missed anything?